# How do I iterate over a hash by ascending value?

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I hvae a hash, whose key is a string, and whose value is a number (a positive integer).  I iterate over pairs like so

```
  my_hash.each do |key, value|
```

My quesiton is, how do I iterate over my hash where each pair is sorted by ascending value?  That is, if my hash is

```
{"a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 1}
```

The "c" => 1 pair will be iterated over first, followed by the "a" => 2, and then the "b" => 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the hash's key value pairs first, then iterate over it.

```
my_hash.sort_by { |_, value| value }.each { |key, value| puts key }
```

If `my_hash = {"a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 1}`, the output is:

> c
>   a
>   b

---

As per the suggestion, you can the use [Array#last](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-last) instance method to simplify.

```
my_hash.sort_by(&:last).each { |key, value| puts key }
```

---

### Enumerable#sort_by

See [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) for the documentation.

The block passed to `sort_by` is called with each key value pair.
The result of `sort_by` is a nested array.

Using the above example:

```
p my_hash.sort_by(&:last)
```

> [["c", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 4]]

Comment: `Hash#sort_by` calls the block with a two element array (which you're deconstructing) so you could say `my_hash.sort_by(&:last)` if you wanted.

Comment: @muistooshort, don't you mean [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)? The class `Hash` has no  instance method by that name. Justin, "You can sort the hash first,.." may be interpreted to mean that the sort produces another hash with the key-value pairs reordered. It might be clearer to say that  you are sorting the hash's key-value pairs, producing an array of two-element arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure, that would be more accurate. I was trying to short-hand my way to saying that all the Enumerable methods send two element arrays to the blocks when used on a Hash. Probably not my best use of English ever :)

Comment: @muistooshort, when I saw `Hash#sort_by` I thought of `Hash#select`, which, unlike `Enumerable#select`, returns a hash (rather than an array).

Comment: Using `last` is much nicer, thanks! I've also edited the answer to make it more clear how `sort_by` works.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 2.7 you can [numbered block parameters](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#numbered-block-parameters) to reference your hash key or hash value in a shorter way. Useful if you need to e.g. convert to a string:

```rb
my_hash.sort_by { _1.to_s }.each {|key, value| puts key }
```